# How to install Spritebuilder?

Tags: github, app-store, spritebuilder

Hello I'm trying to install Spritebuilder but it seems like it's no longer available on the mac app store.

I've tried installing via github, but I'm running into trouble.
I'm getting this error: "`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`" when following the instructions on github.
And I can't locate the git/config file to try the other listed option.

Any idea how I can go about installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you follow "[Getting started with the source](https://github.com/spritebuilder/SpriteBuilder#getting-started-with-the-source)", you must be sure to be in the repo you have cloned:

> Change directory into the top (this) directory of SpriteBuilder and run:

```
git clone https://github.com/apportable/SpriteBuilder
cd SpriteBuilder  <==== important
```

Comment: I believe I did cd into the "Spritebuilder" folder.
Hmm I'll have to try it again. Thank you though!! :)

Comment: Ah, my mistake! I hadn't changed directories into the correct folder.
Figured it out now! Thank you!! :)